# injecting EJB into JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jpa

I have been using EJBs with servlets for many years, but I need to use them in a JSP page and I am struggling. I am using Glassfish 4.1

I have an entity something like this:

```
public class Address implements Serializable, EntityToJson {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name="addressType")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
  private AddressType addressType;

  @Column(name="streetLineOne")
  private String streetLineOne;

  @Column(name="city")
  private String city;

  @Column(name="adState")
  private String state;

  ...
```

and the interface like this:

```
public interface AddressService {
  public Address createAddress(final JsonObject addressPayload) throws AddressException;
  ...    
}
```

So in my Servlet I would do something like:

```
@EJB AddressService addressService;
```

and use it like this

```
Address address = addressService.createAddress(addressJson);
```

How do I do this in JSP? Everything I try doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It's a big design smell to be putting business logic on the JSP.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad idea from design point, but anyway you can get it via lockup in jndi.

Like:

```
AddressService addressService = (AddressService) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/AddressService");
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but what is the right way to interact with the business logic.  If I want to create an Address for example the business logic has the methods to do this and the JSP has the interface for entering the details.  How do I get one to the other? via Servlets perhaps?

Comment: There are few ways depends on your architecture in J2EE for this, first of course would be add your Address entity that was filled up on front end side to the request that will be handled via Servlet in which will be injected your service. And you can write Rest Service for handling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via servlet: https://github.com/readonlynetwork/sandbox/tree/master/jsp-and-ejb

```
request.setAttribute("ejbObj", ejbObj);     
request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```